# how to make label field and text field to appear on same line in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
<div>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Form</legend>
 <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="FirstName">

 <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="LastName">
<label for="Period">Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="Period">
 <p>
        <input type="submit" value="   Send   " />
    </p>
</fieldset>
</div>
}
```

Here i want to make all the label field and text field to appear on same line?How could i do that?

Comment: Use css to style your elements.

Comment: They already do... http://jsfiddle.net/o4h1nbgj/

Comment: I suspect you want something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o4h1nbgj/1/)?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke ,No i want all the label field and text field to come in single line.

Comment: As @David, noted, they already do unless you have override the default css (so what is the problem?)

Comment: you should have mentioned HTML instead of MVC4 in title

Comment: Change parent div style "display:inline" like this https://jsfiddle.net/o4h1nbgj/

Answer (score 0):

Change Parent Div and paragraph display style to inline

```
<div style="display:inline">
<fieldset>
<legend>Form</legend>
<label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="FirstName">
<label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="LastName">
<label for="Period">Date:</label>
<input type="text" name="Period">
<p style="display:inline">
    <input type="submit" value="   Send   " />
</p>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: no its coming one after other,is it because i am using master layout i am not getting?